# How to create an ExtensionObject for filtering in milo OPCUA?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am trying to define a Filter for a Subscription but I dont know how to create the `ExtensionObject` that is needed. Its either a `ByteString` or an `XmlElement` that I am missing but I dont know how or from where to get either one. If I go with a `ByteString` that is `null`, it wont connect to the server.

```
DataChangeFilter filter = new DataChangeFilter(DataChangeTrigger.StatusValue,
            UInteger.valueOf(DeadbandType.Absolute.getValue()), 10.0);

ExtensionObject eoFilter = new ExtensionObject(???, filter.getTypeId());

MonitoringParameters parameters = new MonitoringParameters(clientHandle, 500.0, eoFilter, uint(10), true);
```

What do I insert for "???" in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `ExtensionObject` constructor. Instead, use the static `ExtensionObject.encode(...)` and pass it your `DataChangeFilter`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I totally missed that DataChangeFilter was a UAStructure.

Comment: Please mark the question answered if you've got everything working :)